# JSF 2.2 page, backing bean, page rendering?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a requirement where 2 input values are entered onto JSF 2.2 page. We are using Primefaces controls. These values are then submitted to managed bean method via h:command button.

Then, based upon the values, I want to set a separate output field on the same JSF page to a specific value.

So my issue at the moment is trying to wire a managed bean so that it returns a value back to field on my JSF page which in this case field name is mgrs. The main issue is that I'm dealing with is the third party library that produces the return values and I'm not sure the best approach on how to interface with this library so that I can return the values that I need from it. Also from within my JSF page what would be the best approach from the commandbutton to get the value back from the bean code?

Here is the working portion of my JSF page

```
     <p:panel id="horizontal" header="Horizontal Toggle" toggleable="true" 
      toggleOrientation="horizontal">
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" styleClass="left">

     <h:outputLabel for="basic" value="Enter Latitude:" />
     <p:inplace id="lat">
      <p:inputText value="Latitude" />
     </p:inplace>

      <h:outputLabel for="basic" value="Enter Longitude:" />
      <p:inplace id="long">
        <p:inputText value="Longitude" />
       </p:inplace>

       <p:inplace id="mgrs">
        <p:inputText value="Longitude" />
       </p:inplace>

       <h:commandButton actionlistener="#{coordinates.mgrsFromLatLon(lat, long)}"  update="mgrs" />
```

Here is the third party API:

```
  package com.berico.coords;

  import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Angle; 
  import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.coords.MGRSCoord;
  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

  @ManagedBean(name="coordinates")

  public class Coordinates {

public static String mgrsFromLatLon(double lat, double lon){

    Angle latitude = Angle.fromDegrees(lat);

    Angle longitude = Angle.fromDegrees(lon);

    return MGRSCoord
            .fromLatLon(latitude, longitude)
            .toString();
}

public static double[] latLonFromMgrs(String mgrs){

    MGRSCoord coord = MGRSCoord.fromString(mgrs);

    return new double[]{ 
        coord.getLatitude().degrees, 
        coord.getLongitude().degrees 
    };
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand your question so far. If you add `render="@form"` to your button everything in this form should be updated after the action/actionlistener is completed. Create a [mcve] to clearify your problem.

Comment: @MarkGriffin: Please start reading some jsf ajax tutorials. Start with plain jsf and no PF tags. The usage of the `rendered` attribute on the `h:commandButton` and the contents of this attribute make me think you did not read a decent tutorial yet.

Comment: @MarkGriffin: Might not be, but `h:commandButton ... update="..."` is wrong too. Your addition to the question makes it a bit more clear. But in that case, your title does not match the real problem anymore. "How to return a value from a managed bean (or actionListener)" would be more appropriate and for this, there are multiple questions in StackOverflow if I remember correctly. And the bean contains code constructs that are totally against how JSF works (you do not return anything from  actionListeners and from actions you only return 'views' not some custom object)

Comment: And it might even be more related to "How do I add a coordinate to a map from a bean" or something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447274/cant-populate-table-with-google-map-coordinates-using-primefaces and check https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/basic.xhtml (contains an example to I think of what you want)

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't really need to add coordinate to map. At this juncture I'm simply performing conversions between lat, long -> MGRS and vice versa. Once conversion takes place within third party API, I need to retrieve value from API back to JSF page

Comment: Drop all the map long mgrs stuff. Try to simply update a field when calling an actionListener. There are lots of basic things wrong in your page (mgrs input is not bound to any field) which lead me to think that Oracle ADF had some 'optimizations' that are totally against all JSF principles). And yes, a basic ajax tutorial https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml might already help... Cheers...

Comment: @Kukeltje I get where you are coming from in terms of ajax update...I still need to pass values to the third party API and then get value back from it. I will continue to play around with it

Comment: Okay I figured it out...a big thanks to all who helped especially @Kukeltje...Do I need to post the solution?

Comment: @MarkGriffin: Hmmm... There are not a lot of similar questions here since I suspect not many people make these mistakes (no offence). But when I see your new question, I think you did not actually solve it since it is very closely related and lots of the comments I made here are repeated there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Why not its quite simple.

**Changes in JSF page**

1. Put your elements inside a `<h:panelGrid/>` or something similar component.
2. Give one `id` to your `<h:panelGrid id="panelID"/>`
3. Bind your `<h:outputtext/>` with a variable from your bean.
4. Use rendered attribute in your `<h:outputtext rendered="#{bean.showOutputBox}" />`
5. Now in your button with action use `render` attribute and give id of `pandelgrid` which added in **Step2**

**Changes in Java/bean side**

1. Create a variable(boolean) `showOutputBox = false` with `get/set` method.
2. When you click on sumbitmethod call a action in bean ,in that action method make this(above) declare variable `true` rest JSF will take care.

Comment: I fail to understand this answer in relation to the question. @lastresort seems to be more on 'target'. It seems to be a plain ajax question where OP has no basic knowledge of ajax.

Comment: @Kukeltje Why you always fail to understand the question as well as answer? Dont you think in stackoverflow is for beginner as well.

Comment: Several reasons... Lets start with `h:outputBox`??? No such component exists. Secondly OP talks about a `rerender` and you talk about wrapping things most likely related to making unrendered components rendered but that is not the issue here. But no problem, I'll refrain from comments to get things clear and just downvote... Cheers

Comment: @Kukeltje If you know better than other what OP asking why not you are give answer rather than putting same comment in all question

Comment: @Kukeltje  I do have a lot of knowledge about ajax but at this juncture think its overkill given what I'm trying to accomplish is very basic and should be able to be completed within confines of JSF 2.2 and Primefaces frameworks. Maybe this is a miscalculation on my part though, given we are using JSF 2.2, Primefaces 6.1 and Java 8. I'm re-educating myself in  JSF, and to a degree Java programming because I was away from JSF primarily for 7-8 years because I was doing Oracle ADF programming.